# Cannot find module Interceptor NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I followed the [NestJS's docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) for setting up a interceptor, but i'm facing following issue:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'src/middleware/request.interceptor'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/mypath/dist/product/controller/product.controller.js:15:31)
     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

src/middleware/request.interceptor.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        console.log('Before...');

        const now = Date.now();
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
            tap(() => console.log(`After... ${Date.now() - now}ms`)),
        );
    }
}
```

src/product/controller/product.controller.ts

```js
@Controller('product')
@UseInterceptors(LoggingInterceptor)
export class ProductController {

    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

    @Get()
    findAll(): String {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

src/product/product.module

```js
@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    controllers: [ProductController]
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ProductModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, Logger],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I strictly followed the docs, i already tried to rebuild and delete `dist` folder. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Just found the reason.

The problem is the damn VsCode auto import path.

In `product.controller` the auto generated import was
`import { LoggingInterceptor } from "src/middleware/request.interceptor";` but it should be `import { LoggingInterceptor } from "../../middleware/request.interceptor";`